# How to revolve full path of a symlink?

Tags: ant, groovy, symlink

In Groovy/Ant, I need to get the actual path that a particular symlink points to. For example, if I have some symlink foo pointing at /home/documents/bar

```
foo -> /home/documents/bar
```

Is there a way to take foo and resolve it to a pathname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Java 7, can't you use:

```
println file.canonicalPath
```

To get the path that the link points to?  Where:

```
println file.absolutePath
```

Prints the path to the symlink